# Getting incompatible error for parent child classes java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have a HashMap defined:

```
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<Thing>> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

I do need an ArrayList since I want one key to have multiple values. This was the best solution I found for that problem. 
The Thing class is a parent class for a bunch of other classes. Problem is when I try to add I get an error.

```
 hashmap.put(b, world.ports);
```

This is the error:

```
no suitable method found for put(String,ArrayList<SeaPort>)
method Map.put(String,ArrayList<Thing>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ArrayList<SeaPort> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Thing>)
method AbstractMap.put(String,ArrayList<Thing>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ArrayList<SeaPort> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Thing>)
method HashMap.put(String,ArrayList<Thing>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ArrayList<SeaPort> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Thing>)
```

`
I dont understand this since SeaPort extends Thing isn't it supposed to be compatible? I have read a bunch of upcasting and downcasting threads but I don't see how they apply here.
Here is the Thing class:

```
package seaportprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Thing implements Comparable<Thing>{
String name;
int index;
int parent;
World world;

public Thing(){
    name = null;
    index = 0;
    parent =0;
}

//Thing Scanner Constructor
public Thing (Scanner sc){
if(sc != null){
name = sc.next();
index = sc.nextInt();
parent = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

// Get Index
public int getIndex(){
    return index;
}
//Get Name
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
//Get Parent
public int getParent(){
return parent;
}
//Thing To String
public String toString(){
return name + " " + index;
}
//Auto-Gen Compare Method
@Override
public int compareTo(Thing o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;

}

}//End - Class Thing
```

Here is the SeaPort class:

```
package seaportprogram;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SeaPort extends Thing {
ArrayList<Dock> docks;
ArrayList<Ship> que;
ArrayList<Ship> ships;
ArrayList<Person> persons;

//Sea Port Scanner Constructor
public SeaPort(Scanner sc){

    super(sc);
    docks = new ArrayList<>();
que = new ArrayList<>();
ships = new ArrayList<>();
persons = new ArrayList<>();
}
//Set Docks
public void setDocks(ArrayList<Dock> docks){
    this.docks = docks;
}
//Get Docks
public ArrayList<Dock> getDocks(){
    return docks;
}
//Set Ships
public void setShips(ArrayList<Ship> ships){
    this.ships = ships;
}
//Get Ships
public ArrayList<Ship> getShips(){
    return ships;
}
//Set Que
public void setQue(ArrayList<Ship> que){
    this.que = que;
}
//Get Que
public ArrayList<Ship> getQue(){
    return que;
}
//Sea Port To String
public String toString(){

String string = "\n\n Sea Port: " + super.toString() + "\n";

for(Dock md: docks){
        string += "\n" + md + "\n";
}

string += "\n\n --- List of all ships in Que: ";

for(Ship ms: que){
        string += "\n  > " + ms;
}

string += "\n\n --- List of all Ships:";

for(Ship ms: ships){
        string += "\n  > " + ms;
    }

string += "\n\n --- List of all Persons:";

for(Person mp: persons){
        string += "\n  > " + mp;
}
return string;

}//End 


}// End Sea Port Class
```

This is World class:

```
package seaportprogram;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class World extends Thing{

ArrayList<SeaPort> ports;
PortTime time;

//World Scanner Constructor
public World(Scanner sc){
    super (sc);
ports = new ArrayList<>();
}
//Set Ports
}
```

Any way to make this happen?
TIA!
update:
I am trying to print the map and I get an null pointer exception. I think this is because the list is being initialized both in seaport and in the MyHashMap class. I cant seem to find a way to get around this and I'm not even sure this is the reason for the error. Here is the toString():

```
          public String toString(){
        if(map.isEmpty())
         {
             System.out.println("The hashMap is empty");
             return "empty";
         }
        String display=" ";
        Iterator<String> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            display =display + itr.next();
            Iterator<ArrayList<T>> itr2 = map.values().iterator();
            while (itr2.hasNext()) {
                display +=itr2.next();
            }
        }

    return display;
    }
```

and this is the call to it from the gui:

```
 jta.setText(map.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList<Derived_Class>` does not extend `ArrayList<Base_Class>`.

If you want to use an HashMap like this, one solution could be to write your own wrapper class using templates:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyHashMap<T extends Thing> {
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>> map;

    public MyHashMap() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(String s, T element) {
        ArrayList<T> list = null;
        if ((list = map.get(s)) == null)
            map.put(s, list = new ArrayList<T>());
        list.add(element);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> get(String s) {
        return map.get(s);
    }
}
```

if you want an HashMap of SeaPorts, you can create a new HashMap like this,

```
MyHashMap<SeaPort> map = new MyHashMap<SeaPort>();
```

and use custom setters and getters to access the arraylists

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try that.

Comment: I initialized the MyHashMap with: MyHashMap(); and I am trying to add to the map with 
    MyHashMap.add(b, port);
and i get this error:
    non-static method add(String,T) cannot be referenced from a static context
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Thing declared in class MyHashMap
----

Comment: add is a class method of MyHashMap, so you have to call it on the map you initialized, i.e. MyHashMap<Your_Thing_Class> map = new MyHashMap<Your_Thing_Class>(); map.add("string", obj);

Comment: can you possibly take a look at the question again I have added more of the new code. I'm getting another error when I try to print. Thanks again

Comment: this in another question, it is good practice to have only one per topic, to keep things clean. you should accept my answer if you think solved your problem, than you can open another topic about your exception, give all the details, and i or someone else will be very happy to help you

Comment: Thank you for your help Todde! I finally learned how to accept an answer. But have chosen not to carry this out. It is too abstract for me couldnt get it to work. I'll try another way.

Answer (score 1):

`Seaport` may extend `Thing`, but `ArrayList<SeaPort>` does not extend `ArrayList<Thing>`.

If you just want to store a map of Strings to Things, you don't need ArrayList. If you really want to map Strings to Lists of Things, then you can't do it like this.

Comment: I do need an ArrayList since I want one key to have multiple values. This was the best solution I found for that problem. Any way to make this happen?